# Does monotonic function imply continuity?

Tags: integration, monotone-functions, continuity

My formula book states that in order to apply variable substitution on an integral, i.e use the formula:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx =  \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(t))g'(t)dt 
$$
$g(t)$ needs to be a monotonic function in $g^{-1}(a)  \leq t  \leq g^{-1}(b)$. However, the substitution works for example for the Gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^ \infty  u^{z-1}e^{-u}du
$$
Applying the substitution $u = g(t) = \ln{\frac{1}{t}}$ in $\Gamma (z)$, one obtains
$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^1 [\ln (\frac{1}{t})]^{z-1}dt 
$$
which also seem to give correct results (ref: mathworld.wolfram.com). But there is a discontinuity in $0$. My formula book begins stating the conditions for a monotonic function for a continuous function in the closed interval $[x,y]$. I interpret this as one condition for monotonicity is that the function first of all be continuous in the closed interval. Or can a function be monotonic without being continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's two related points to make to answer your question:

1. A function can certainly be monotonic but not continuous. Consider
   $$H(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 0 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
2. If one thinks of substituions as $u = f(x)$, then $f$ should usually at least be continuous and monotonic on the open interval of your integration $(a, b)$. If there is a discontinuity only at an endpoint, then often things "just work out" if you treat it as normal. If there is a discontinuity at the endpoint, then strictly, one should consider an interval $[a + \epsilon, b]$ and take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

Generally, the monotonicity is required so that you don't "lose" part of your interval. For example, consider what would happen if we blindly went ahead and tried to substitute $u = x^2$ in a rather trivial integral
$$I = \int_{-1}^1 dx = \int_1^1 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}} \; du$$
We've ended up with $1$ at both endpoints of our interval - this is complete rubbish! In much the same way, you'd never try to substitute $u = 1$ either - it's not a good parametrisation (in both the formal and informal senses) of your region of integration.

---

*Edit*: Raoul correctly points out in the comment thread below that monotonicity is not necessary whatsoever to perform substitutions of the form $x = f(u)$. One should consider my answer more in the context of $u = f(x)$, where we exploit monotonicity to provide an inverse (recasting the problem as x = f^{-1}(u)$, and then defer to Raoul's comment (a formally correct statement of "integration by substitution").

Comment: Regarding your last example, you do not really substitute $u = x^2$, but rather $x = \sqrt{u}$, which cannot work since $x$ can be negative. In general, there is no need for monotonicity: for any continuous $f, g$, we have
$$
\int_a^b f(g(x)) g'(x) \: \mathrm{d} x = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) \: \mathrm{d} u.
$$
This is what we informally write as substituting $u$ by $g(x)$ and $\mathrm{d}u$ by $g'(x) \: \mathrm{d}x$. Of course, care needs to be taken when we "substitute" for instance $x = \cos u$.

Comment: True, you're quite right, thank you very much. I suppose the problem here is that we (or, I, at least) often think of substitution, in the context of this comment, as $x = g^{-1}(u)$ and hence the monotonicity allows us to apply this via a well-defined inverse.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The book states that the function g must be monotonic in the closed interval bounded by the new integration limits. So that would include the endpoints too. I guess that the function could be monotonic according to this definition, similarly to your example 1 above. What made my question it is that the function ln(1/t) lacks a derivative in t = 0, so how could you take this for granted?